# What is the best way to develop a C# project with a MySQL backend?

Tags: c#, mysql

So I'm using C# 2010 Express and wondering what the best toolset is for developing a C# project with a MySQL backend?  I know what if you use SQL Server Compact edition from within C# it will let you access the DB directly from the IDE.  Is there a similar way to integrate the development with a remote MySQL Database?

Also, is MySQL a versatile enough solution for writing a program with C#?  I am looking to build a seperate PHP web site (a reporting portal) that will access the MySQL data.  I'd love to go open source all the way, but it seems like C# is the best app to create the app I'm trying to create (touch screen interface for data entry).

Comment: Why don't you use C# for that web app as well?

Comment: And honestly, why not use SQL Server Express Edition?  Unless you plan to go over 4GB, it's free.

Comment: Well, I am a PHP developer, and I would rather use MySQL as the backend.  The data entry Windows app is just for the front end app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is

http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/fusion/

But it's not free and is a plugin which you can't use with Express.  There is no way to do this with Express as you can't add onto the basic functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I program a database related homepage I always use [HeidiSql](http://www.heidisql.com/) and mysql.  Both of them are easy to figure out and fast to use.

From their site:

> HeidiSQL is a lightweight, Windows
>   based interface for MySQL databases.
>   It enables you to browse and edit
>   data, create and edit tables, views,
>   procedures, triggers and scheduled
>   events. Also, you can export structure
>   and data either to SQL file, clipboard
>   or to other servers.

All you do is install Mysql, set up a pass and username. and it's up and running.

Then all that's left is to install Heidisql. Heidisql it is a free program.  If you need more details on how to attach heidi to your database please do write again.